# Basic React issues .. equire('react/addons') is deprecated. Access using require('react-addons-{addon}') instead

Tags: reactjs

//main.jsx

```
var React = require('react/addons');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');


var GroceryItemList = require('./components/GroceryItemList.jsx');

ReactDOM.render('<GroceryItemList/>', app);
```

//GroceryItemList.jsx

```
var React = require('react/addons');

module.exports = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Grocery Listify</h1>
      </div>
    )
  }
})
```

//index.html

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
Hello world
  <div id="app"></div>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Errors:

```
warning.js:45 Warning: require('react/addons') is deprecated. Access using require('react-addons-{addon}') instead.

Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: ReactDOM.render(): Invalid component element. Instead of passing an element string, make sure to instantiate it by passing it to React.createElement.
```

Not sure how to proceed at this point ?

Comment: Please remove the warning from the post, it's irrelevant to the error and causing false hits on this question for people searching for the solution to the warning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not with the warning, it's with the error at the line below it.

You need to replace

```
ReactDOM.render('<GroceryItemList/>', app);
```

by

```
ReactDOM.render(<GroceryItemList/>, app);
```

And as for the warning, I think you can just use

```
var React = require('react');
```

Comment: No. I have `var React = require('react');` and I render components without quotes `ReactDOM.render(<GroceryItemList/>, app);` but I still get the warning. So it is neither about quotes nor about `require('react');` or `require('react/addons');`

Answer (score 0):

just do it like this:

//main.jsx

```
var React = require('react');
var render = require('react-dom').render;

var GroceryItemList = require('./components/GroceryItemList.jsx');

render('<GroceryItemList/>', app);
```

//GroceryItemList.jsx

```
var React = require('react');

module.exports = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Grocery Listify</h1>
      </div>
    )
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this.
First install `react-addons` as a seperate module:

`npm install react-addons --save`

Second,change the import like this:

```
   import React from 'react';
   import {LinkedStateMixin,PureRenderMixin} from 'react-addons';
```

then you can use the addons `LinkedStateMixin` and `PureRenderMixin`

or like this:

```
var React = require('react');
var addons = require('react-addons');
var LinkedStateMixin = addons.LinkedStateMixin;
var PureRenderMixin = addons.PureRenderMixin;
```